# Switch en consulta SQL y VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Tengo una tabla con varios campos tipo boolean (accciones, preparada, finalizada). Necesito obtener un campo en el que se evalúen esos campos y, dependiendo de sus valores, devuelva una cosa u otra.

Había pensado en utilizar switch:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT detalle_prep.N_PREP, 
    Switch (
        detalle_prep.ACCIONES = FALSE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = FALSE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = FALSE , 
        'Pendiente generar acciones de trabajo',
        detalle_prep.ACCIONES = TRUE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = FALSE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = FALSE , 
        'Pendiente preparar almacén',
        detalle_prep.ACCIONES = TRUE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = TRUE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = FALSE , 
        'Pendiente cerrar en Adaia',
        detalle_prep.ACCIONES = TRUE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = TRUE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = TRUE , 
        'Pendiente de contabilizar'
    )
    AS SITUACION
FROM detalle_prep;
```

Y, aunque funciona (no hay error de sintaxis), estoy obteniendo resultados ambiguos (misma preparación y distintas **SITUACIONES** por lo que me pregunto si esta opción, utilizando **AND**, es correcta. De no serlo, ¿qué alternativa hay?.

Cualquier idea es bienvenida.

**Nota**: los datos están almacenados en un Access y los ataco desde Excel.

Comment: Solo una duda: ¿por qué la etiqueta vba? No veo la relación y yo vine por eso :D

Comment: Jajaja, porque todo lo que tengo está montado en VBA y en VBA no puedo hacer un CASE con SQL que era mi primera idea y tiré por Switch. Y con ese switch no tengo claro si es posible anidar todos esos AND ni sé si se están evaluando todos. 
El caso es que no falla y devuelve datos pero mi duda era esa, si está bien formado el switch. :-) Gracias.

Comment: Estos cuatro casos no están evaluados:

1   detalle_prep.ACCIONES = TRUE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = FALSE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = TRUE , 
 2  detalle_prep.ACCIONES = FALSE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = TRUE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = TRUE , 
 3  detalle_prep.ACCIONES = FALSE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = FALSE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = TRUE , 
 4  detalle_prep.ACCIONES = FALSE AND detalle_prep.PREPARADA = TRUE AND detalle_prep.FINALIZADA = FALSE ,

Comment: Hola, cierto, pero no los evalúo porque el resto del código de la aplicación no permite que se den esos casos. No puedo poner en true el campo FINALIZADA si el resto de campos no son verdaderos, y eso lo controlo aparte. Gracias.

Comment: Aunque no se esperen dichos resultados, deberías incluirlos para evaluar por qué tienes resultados no esperados. Depura el programa y estudia los resultados. Ten en cuenta, por ejemplo, si dichos campos pueden tener valores nulos, ya que de tenerlos no cumplirán alguna condición y se salen del switch.